# VB Application Security - Digital Signatures/CheckSums

Tags: vb.net, digital-signature

I'm creating an application *for a select group* of people to use. But since it'll be free-ware I can't afford to buy a digital signature to authenticate the source as me. Do I have any other option? Are there any tools in windows I could take advantage of? Any free (third party) tools that I could use to increase the chances my app wont be flagged as potentially malicious? I understand that obviously these things aren't the easiest to come by, but I'd like something to at least say the applications not been tampered with.

Can you please advise me on any tools or methods I could use.

Comment: Why do you need a digital signature? Most programs don't make use of digital signatures and it's perfectly normal to ship your application without one. A digital signature can be manipulated and will not stop the program from being flagged as potentially malicious.

Answer (score 0):

No, in the end these things are about trust, and unless you can get a key trusted at the location where they want to verify the binary, you cannot confer trust of the library.

Key trust is normally established using a certificate that was created for you. Buying a signature would only make sense if there is a separate party signing the code as a service.

Of course there are other ways to trust an application; e.g. you can distribute the source and allow builds of the application at a location that the user can trust. But that won't be as convenient as receiving a signed binary, if the system has been setup to mark those as trusted.